# Get all possible combinations from a list of lists by picking one item from each list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists, and I would like to get all possible combinations by picking one item from each list.

For example the following list:

```
l = [[1,2],[3],[4,5,6],[7],[8,9]]
```

The output should be:

```
1,3,4,7,8
1,3,5,7,8
1,3,6,7,8
1,3,4,7,9
1,3,5,7,9
1,3,6,7,9
2,3,4,7,8
2,3,5,7,8
2,3,6,7,8
2,3,4,7,9
2,3,5,7,9
2,3,6,7,9
```

The number of lists and their items is random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> l = [[1,2],[3],[4,5,6],[7],[8,9]]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(*l))
[(1, 3, 4, 7, 8), (1, 3, 4, 7, 9), (1, 3, 5, 7, 8), (1, 3, 5, 7, 9), (1, 3, 6, 7, 8), (1, 3, 6, 7, 9), (2, 3, 4, 7, 8), (2, 3, 4, 7, 9), (2, 3, 5, 7, 8), (2, 3, 5, 7, 9), (2, 3, 6, 7, 8), (2, 3, 6, 7, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) do the job for you

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: l = [[1,2],[3],[4,5,6],[7],[8,9]]

In [3]: product(*l)
Out[3]: <itertools.product at 0x7f012ba3e780>

In [4]: list(product(*l))
Out[4]: 
[(1, 3, 4, 7, 8),
 (1, 3, 4, 7, 9),
 (1, 3, 5, 7, 8),
 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9),
 (1, 3, 6, 7, 8),
 (1, 3, 6, 7, 9),
 (2, 3, 4, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 4, 7, 9),
 (2, 3, 5, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 5, 7, 9),
 (2, 3, 6, 7, 8),
 (2, 3, 6, 7, 9)]
```